# SNMP get interface number

Tags: snmp

Does someone know how to get a interface number for SNMP for nic cards? And how or with what, a SNMP walk?

I have some cards which have the same OID in SNMP but change the port randomly. I was wondering if there was a command I could send from Windows or Linux to get the interface numbers or list all interfaces with their ports like this:
Found standard interfaces:

```
1: (001) lo,Connected,10 MBit/s,Software Loopback,
2: (002) eth0,Connected,100 MBit/s,Ethernet,
3: (003) eth1,Not Connected,0 KBit/s,Ethernet,
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SNMP tables are ordered by an index that can change between systems and reboots.  For this reason you should always look up the index values of tables that can have multiple entries before looking up associated statistics and not rely solely on the OID remaining static.

That being said, `snmptable` will do this for you in a pinch!

```
snmptable -v2c -c <community string> <hostname> IF-MIB::ifTable
```

There are many more columns that you'd like so you could clean up the results with `awk`, like so:

```
snmptable -CH -v2c -c <community string> <hostname> IF-MIB::ifTable | awk 'BEGIN { OFS="," } { print $1, $2, $3, $5 } '
```

Comment: Thanks but I get command not found on a Linux box when I run "snmptable". I have the service installed and running on the box but the one I run the command and so the one Im connecting to. And the service is working since I get data via SNMP from a monitoring platform from them.

Comment: Many distributions separate the utilities from the server.  What distribution are you using?

Comment: Centos and RHEL net-snmp is installed.

Comment: Looks like `snmptable` is provided by `net-snmp-utils`.  Try that one out.

Comment: OK I got one for windows and commands works except for the one you posted. I think the syntax is wrong.

Comment: I got this to work but I need to displays results only from specific MIBS. For example if one ethernet card is called "hobie" my questions was rather how do I send it a command so it tells me on which interface port "hobie" is running. I don´t need all the data, just to get the results for that specific line.

Comment: Could you use `grep`?

Comment: snmpwalk -v 1 -c pass serverIP ifDescr. this works and displays all nics. Does someone know how to filter this per STRING? I tried this "ifDescr |grep "STRING: nic0"|grep IF-MIB::ifDescr" but this gives me an error. Being nic0 here the nic I want to display.